# How to reset a loop?

Tags: r, loops, reset

Hi everyone I have this dataset

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
input<- frame_data(
  ~member_id,   ~fill_date   ,  ~drug, ~days_supply, 
  "603",       "02/17/2005",    "a",    30,         
  "603",       "06/13/2005",    "a",    30,       
  "603",       "08/11/2005",    "a",    30,           
  "603",       "06/12/2006",    "b",    15,
  "603",       "05/09/2006",    "b",    30
  )
```

I am trying to create a variable called "time" which indicates  the number of time the variable "drug" appears. So the output should look like this

```
output<- frame_data(
  ~member_id,   ~fill_date   ,  ~drug, ~days_supply, ~time,
  "603",       "02/17/2005",    "a",    30,           1,
  "603",       "06/13/2005",    "a",    30,           2,
  "603",       "08/11/2005",    "a",    30,           3,
  "603",       "06/12/2006",    "b",    15,           1,
  "603",       "05/09/2006",    "b",    30            2
  )
```

in other terms I'am looking for a sort of loop that can reset every time the "drug" variable changes 
I've tried this code

```
time<-1
i<-2
j<-1
while (i <=nrow(input)){
  if (input[i,3,drop=]==input[i-1,3,drop=]){
    j<-i
    time<-c(time,j)
  }else{
    j<-1
    time<-c(time,j)
  }
  i<-i+1
}
```

but of course it dosen't work since the i could not be reset because it indicates the row index while verifying the condition in the same times.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `dplyr`, so use `group_by`, not a loop.

```
input %>% group_by(drug) %>% mutate(time = 1:n())
```

Probably you want to add `member_id` to the group by as well, but since you don't mention I don't include. If so, just `group_by(drug, member_id)` instead of `group_by(drug)`.